# Issue Hardlink/Junction not working when chroot all users to c:/share dir in Windows OpenSSH Server 2019

Tags: ssh, sftp, chroot, hardlink, windows-server-2019

Issue Hardlink/Junction not working when chroot all users to c:/share dir in Windows OpenSSH Server 2019.

**Link Created**
mklink /d E "E:"
mklink /d F "F:"

**Entry in sshd_config file**
ChrootDirectory c:/share

Now When I connect to my Server via SCP using SFTP. I landed on the Share Dir.
I am able to browse E and F Drive from Share Dir.
However I am NOT able to view or copy any file for E & F .

What I figured out is that via Hardlink or junction Link I can only see the Dir, But I can't view the content of the file and can't even copy the file.

My Requirement is to 
Use Windows 2019 Server with OPENSSH Integrated with Active Directory
Create hard Link for 5 Hard drive (2Tb Each ) to Share Folder
So when user connect via SCP, then land in C:/Share Dir, and then from their they can go D,E,F,G Drive

I need the SSH functionality integrated with active director

Comment: Your question asks about hardlinks and junctions, but the text of your question describes the creation of a symbolic link (the `/d` option).  Which is it?  Did you try using `/j` instead?  (It should also be noted that you cannot hardlink directories.)

Comment: Another option in your situation would be to create empty directories in the share directory and mount the drives to them.